# How can I test an abstract class using Espresso?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing, android-espresso

Suppose I make an abstract `BaseActivity` with a [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html), like this:

```
/**
 * A base activity that handles common functionality in the app. 
 * This includes the Toolbar
 */
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Primary toolbar
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResId) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResId);
        setToolbar();
    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        if (mToolbar == null) {
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (mToolbar != null) {              
                mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.navigation_drawer_description_ally));
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a `MainActivity` that extends this `BaseActivity`, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The layouts are:

`toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is: How can I test `BaseActivity` using [espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/)? To, for example, check if the `Toolbar` exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a TestActivity for testing your abstract BaseActivity Class. But remember, this class should only override the necessary method and code to avoid any effect to the BaseActivity  class.

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And then you can use your Espresso to

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class BaseActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> mTestActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<TestActivity>(TestActivity.class, true, false);
    @Before
    public void set() {
        //setup your things
    }
    @Test
    public void testRequest1() {
        mTestActivityActivityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare this activity in th androidTest module manifest.